# Why advertisingId is missing in firebase analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

It is stated in firebase analytics documents that the advertisingId will be automatically collected for each user with events but I am getting it as null for all events in analytics console (Big query).

We are using firebase library version 11.4.2 in our android application and have a privacy policy added in google play console.

Also, it was stated that if advertisingId is missing, vendorId will be collected but we are getting vendorId only for few events. What could be the possible reason for not getting advertisingId/vendorId with events?

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly for questions about how the SDK works. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Double check your manifest to make sure you're not excluding the ID. Also, you're using a very old version of firebase so the documentation might not be true for your version.